# understanding javascript If else

Tags: javascript

What will be execution sequence of the following code?

```
return (year % 100 === 0) ? (year % 400 === 0) : (year % 4 === 0);
```

This code is actually just to check a bunch of conditions for the expected result so if anyone could clarify please.Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a check for a leap year.

Comment: This checks if `year` is a leap year

Comment: This is if else shorthand 
if(true)? true: false

Comment: It's unclear what you don't understand. The logic? The [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)? [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, it would be good to note what _specifically_ you don't understand, rather that stating you're confused and throwing out a piece of code. "I'm confused about fish; explain please" is much less answerable than "I heard fish breathe water, how is that possible?"

Answer (score -1):

If `year` is a multiple of 100, it returns whether `year` is a multiple is 400. Eg

```
100 -> false
200 -> false
400 -> true
```

If `year` is not a multiple of 100, it returns whether `year` is a multiple of 4. Eg

```
1 -> false
2 -> false
3 -> false
4 -> true
5 -> false
8 -> true
```